# Нажатие на кнопку (normal && press down)

Tags: android, алгоритм

```
public class Button : MonoBehaviour {

    public Sprite bigbutton2, bigbutton2_down;

    void Update () {
    }

    void OnMouseDown () {

        GetComponent <SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = bigbutton2;
    }

    void OnMouseUp () {

        GetComponent <SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = bigbutton2_down;
    }

    void OnMouseUpAsButton () {
        switch (gameObject.name) {
        case "Play":
            Application.LoadLevel ("Scr");
            break;
        case "Sergey":
            Application.OpenURL ("http://vk.com/stil1960");
            break;

        }

    }

}
```

У меня есть кнопка под названием `Sergey`, по нажатию на эту кнопку я должен перескакивать на сайт. На сайт пеперходит, все отлично.
У этой кнопки есть два спрайта, это

> 1) bigbutton2 (обычный вид)
>
> 2) bigbutton2_down (когда на кнопку нажал)

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку bigbutton2, то у меня на постоянной основе включаеться bigbutton2_down

Как сделать проверку? Что когда идет нажатие на кнопку(спрайт) bigbutton2, идет нажатие bigbutton2_down и опять возвращаеться к спрайту(кнопке) bigbutton2.

Comment: Вам нужно на отпускание мыши, ставить обратно спрайт bigbutton2, а на нажатие bigbutton2_down, сейчас у вас всё наоборот

Comment: Пипец.... Спасибо. А можно ли как-то реализовать сюда, когда на кнопку навел, то менятсья спрайт кнопки??

Comment: а что понимается под наведением в Android?

Comment: Хотя, да.. Чего это я... Это же на пк только мышкой наводить)))))

Comment: андроид прекрасно работает с мышкой, и вот "когда на кнопку навел, то меняется спрайт" очень даже реализуемо)